# ModuleNotFound errors on PyPy

Tags: python, pypy, python-chess

I recently started using PyPy, and the chess engine I'm working on uses `import chess`- This runs on CPython well, but if I run the program on PyPy, it just gives me a ModuleNotfound error- `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chess'`. I tried `pip3 install chess` on the VSCode terminal that runs with PyPy, but the terminal told me the chess module was already installed (`Requirement already satisfied: chess in /Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages`.) I also checked the PyPy docs, but since I'm pretty inexperienced I couldn't get what it said. How do I get modules running on PyPy?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might be using the wrong python environment when calling `pip3`. Can you run `pypy3 -m pip install chess` instead and try again?

Comment: @Marcel I get a Command not found: pypy3 error.

Comment: How are you running your program with PyPy?

Comment: I'm running the code on Virtual Studio Code, by just changing the interpreter.

Comment: Could someone please help? I've been stuck with this for a long time and I don't have enough reputation to get a bounty.